# magicalRecord setup with icloud wont reload persisted data

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

The following line fails to persist any data, although there is a sqlite file at library/Application Support/Appname/Appname.sqlite that has header information as set from the model.

```
 [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"128DBLAH422.com.company.appname.ubiquitycoredata" localStoreNamed:@"Appname.sqlite"];
```

- ICloud is also started, as the kMagicalRecordPSCDidCompleteiCloudSetupNotification notification is fired.
- I loose all data on the next run, although I am able to save correctly throughout run-time ('Finished saving' on main thread) and have all (as far as I've seen) data available in-memory.

The following saves and persists properly w/ an sqlite file at the same directory path:

```
 [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"Appname.sqlite"];
```

- I wonder why when iCloud is enabled that I'm seeing the DB in "library/Application Support/Appname/". Is that correct?

On one device w/ 5.0.1, I get the following error on runs after first run:

```
 Error: Can't resolve how to assign objects to stores; Coordinator does not have any stores
```

on iPad and simulator, no error, but no data also.

Also... After first run with setup core data with icloud (1st line in did finish launching):

```
  [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"128DBLAH422.com.company.appname.ubiquitycoredata" localStoreNamed:@"Appname.sqlite"];
```

any future run using

```
  [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"Appname.sqlite"];
```

instead of icloud setup will recover the data that wouldn't have appeared on next run otherwise. If I add data on first run with icloud, re-run with icloud and add no data, then run without icloud, the data is there.

- Is there a method of loading the store on subsequent runs that is unique from when creating it for the first time?

Comment: Did you find out the problem here?

Comment: Didn't actually. This bug report is on github, feel free to chime-in here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/384